# How to take max value and replace it in drived colomn in data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to azure data factory. I need a help in the following implementation -

input:

Key,  col3

1,5

2,6

3,7

Desired output:

Key, col3

1,3

2,6

3,7

Here key=1, col3 value is replaced with 3 (maximum of key)

I have a requirement to replace one column data with maximum value of other column. I want to take the maximum of key column and replace the value in column3 with that max value. This should be done only for the row key=1.

I used derived column transformation and iif expression. But how to take maximum value?

Comment: Use Window Transformation and get the maximum value and use that maximum value in derived column transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Max()** or any aggregate functions cannot be used directly in derived column transformation. Therefore, use Window transformation and take the maximum of the column key. Use this value in derived column transformation.
- I tried to repro this with sample data and below is the approach.
- Sample source data is taken.
  [image]

img:1 Source data preview

- Window transformation is taken next to source transformation. Window columns is selected. New column named **max_key** is given as column name. Expression is `max(key)`.

[image]

img:2 Window Transformation settings

- maximum value of key at the entire table data is assigned to **max_key** column.

[image]

img:3 Windows transformation data preview

- Derived column transformation is taken. Expression for the column **mark** is
  `iif(key=='1',max_key,mark)`

[image]

img:4 Derived column transformation settings

- Here, I tried to assign the maximum value of key to mark where key=1 and remaining values of the column is assigned as original mark value.

[image]

img:5 Derived Column transformation data preview.

- By this way you can use the maximum value in derived column transformation.